# Verify user Facebook Login using Facebook SDK for Android

Tags: android

I am using the Facebook SDK to be able to make a Facebook login in my application. When my application starts, I want to check if the user is already logged-in into his account or not. If the user is already logged-in, my application will show the main interface. But if the user is not logged-in, my application is supposed to show the login-in dialog. I am stocked at determining whether the user is already logged-in or not. How will I check it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
if(mFacebook.isSessionValid())
{
    // show main interface
}
else
{
    // show login dialog
}
```

Comment: `mFacebook.isSessionValid()` always returns false. What will I do?

Comment: did you [save the access token](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/mobile/android/build/#token) after authorization?

Answer (score 1):

hi go through this site [HACKBOOK](https://github.com/facebook/facebook-android-sdk/tree/master/examples) you ll find example for facebook sessions & many more. all the best